# Automate GUI designed in Flash using Selenium RC

Tags: selenium-rc

I have a question on Flash Automation. I want to automate my website which is in flash. where i have to login, create users , scroll down and find users.

Can i Automate it using selenium RC if not please suggest some good open source tools.

Thanks

Comment: <object name="app" width="100%" height="100%" align="middle" id="app" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true"/>

Answer (score 0):

If you don't manage to pull off what you want to do using Selenium RC. Try using Sikuli (*found at http://www.sikuli.org/* ). You can use the Sikuli IDE, which works a lot like Selenium IDE, or try using the libs with java per example. They've got some examples on the site where you'll see how to use the image recognition to find certain elements and add/edit the data present there. Hope this helps.